# Transparent Swipeable drawer Material-UI

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, material-ui

I need to know how to apply a 'transparent' style porperty background to my SwipeableDrawer component from Material UI... Since the component creates another component in my html file when it renders i cannot change his background from my code.
I tried to put some , but it seems that the component doesn`t like it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As stated in Material-ui [Docs](https://material-ui.com/api/drawer/) you can override the style of `Modal` using `ModalProps`. 
Using the `BackdropProps` of `Modal` you can able to set the background to transparent.

Create a `styles` variable and apply the necessary styles.

```js
const styles = {
  BackdropProps: {
    background: 'transparent'
  }
};
```

Apply the style to the root of `Backdrop` using `classes` property

```js
<SwipeableDrawer ModalProps={{
          BackdropProps:{
            classes:{
              root:classes.BackdropProps
            }
          }
        }}
        {...otherProps}>
```

Have a look at overriding components with classes in the [docs](https://material-ui.com/customization/overrides/#overriding-with-classes)

Comment: `invisible` is also one of the [`<Backdrop>` props](https://material-ui.com/api/backdrop/#props) in case that helps anyone.